# Avoiding a column from group by clause in a sql query

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have this SP, where am trying to insert records in an Oracle target table (11.2). Here in the subquery naming as 'a' where i have a column `PROJECT` which is one of the joining condition for the subquery 'b', but here I am not getting the desired result if I put the column 'project' in the group by clause in subquery 'a'.

But at same time I need to refer the same as one of the joining conditions of subquery 'b'.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC1
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE
      SELECT a.SECT,
             a.REG,
             a.USRN,
             a.PRO_CT,
             a.CATG,
             a.TLT,
             a.SN_YR_MN,
             a.SN_YR,
             a.SN_MN,
             a.UNIQUE_ISSUES_CNT,
             a.FILES_SN_ISS_CT,
             b.TOT_FILES_SN_CT,
             b.TOT_SN_CT,
             CURRENT_DATE
        FROM (  SELECT SECT,
                       REG,
                       USRN,
                       PROJECT,
                       COUNT (DISTINCT CONCAT (PROJECT, SOLUTION)) PRO_CT,
                       CATG,
                       TLT,
                       SN_YR_MN,
                       SN_YR,
                       SN_MN,
                       COUNT (DISTINCT ISSUE_ID) UNIQUE_ISSUES_CNT,
                       COUNT (DISTINCT PATH) FILES_SN_ISS_CT
                  FROM table1
              GROUP BY SECT,
                       REG,
                       PROJECT,
                       USRN,
                       CATG,
                       TLT,
                       SN_YR_MN,
                       SN_YR,
                       SN_MN) a
             JOIN
             (  SELECT USRN,
                       PROJECT,
                       SECT,
                       REG,
                       SN_YR_MN,
                       SN_YR,
                       SN_MN,
                       COUNT (DISTINCT RPT_SCAN_SUMMARY.PATH) TOT_FILES_SN_CT,
                       COUNT (DISTINCT RPT_SCAN_SUMMARY.SCAN_ID) TOT_SN_CT
                  FROM table2
              GROUP BY USRN,
                       PROJECT,
                       SECT,
                       REG,
                       SN_YR_MN,
                       SN_YR,
                       PROJECT,
                       SN_MN) b
                ON     a.USRN = b.USRN
                   AND a.SECT = b.SECT
                   AND a.REG = b.REG
                   AND a.SN_YR_MN = b.SN_YR_MN
                   AND a.SN_YR = b.SN_YR
                   AND a.SN_MN = b.SN_MN
                   AND a.PROJECT = b.PROJECT;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks Senthil.  You said `but here I am not getting the desired result`.  Can you describe what the 'desired result' is with some example data?  If you are going to join on a field (such as `PROJECT`), including it `group by` to drive the aggregation is important so the join can provide appropriate data to the aggregate.

Comment: If i use the project in any aggregate function in subquery a (say avg(project)) ..how can i refer the same project value in subquery b. like a.project=b.project

Comment: Thanks Senthil.  Presumably `table1` and `table2` join on `project` and one has a constraint to the other, or to some common parent.  Joining on a derivation of `project` such as `avg`, `min`, `max`, etc. could hide legitimate joins or introduce  spurious joins.  There's a chance it could meet the need, but it could be dangerous.  Without some data to evaluate, I wouldn't recommend joining on an aggregated/derived data.  Have you tried joining `table1` and `table2` before aggregating?  Could you please include some example data and desired result?